# Highcharts: xAxis label of bar chart are overlapped

Tags: highcharts

How can I change height of the rows depending on the number of lines for labels?

[Actual behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYClP.jpg)

[Expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEpgq.png)

You can see Highchart options below:

Options:

```js
        var options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'bar',
                reflow: false,
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    minPointLength: 3,
                    dataLabels: {
                      enabled: true,
                      crop: false,
                      overflow: "none"
                    },
                pointWidth: 20+11,
                    pointPadding: 5
                }
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: xData,
                labels: {
                    step: 1,
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '100%',
                        color: '#000000'
                    }
              }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Could you share a demo with your issue? By default, the label with a long category name should be positioned like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nt3xb7sz/ or be cropped https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vs0x87gq/

Comment: @SebastianWędzel i can only share options with you

Comment: @SebastianWędzel i have added code. FYI we use 4.0.0 version of Highchart

Comment: I tried to reproduce your case but it seems that even in the 4 version long labels are cropped. https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tk719zh2/